# I don't know whether my valid type is wrong or what

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am new to spring boot. I want to validator check so that the first name and last name cannot be equal. I don't know my code is correct or wrong for the LastNameValidator.java. I use the user object instead of just the last name to check and I get the error. No validator could be found for constraint 'com.example.workbook31.LastName' validating type 'java.lang.String'. Check configuration for 'lastName'.

My LastNameValidator.java code

```java
package com.example.workbook31;

import jakarta.validation.ConstraintValidator;
import jakarta.validation.ConstraintValidatorContext;

public class LastNameValidator implements ConstraintValidator<LastName, User> {
    @Override
    public boolean isValid(User user, ConstraintValidatorContext context){
        if(user.getFirstName() != user.getLastName() ){
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
    
}
```

My LastName.java code

```java
package com.example.workbook31;

import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

import jakarta.validation.Constraint;
import jakarta.validation.Payload;

@Target(ElementType.FIELD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy = LastNameValidator.class)
public @interface LastName {
    String message() default "First Name cannot equal to Last Name";
    Class<?>[] groups() default {};
    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
    
}
```

My ApplicationController.java

```java
package com.example.workbook31;


import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;

import jakarta.validation.Valid;

@Controller
public class ApplicationController {
    
    List<User> users = new ArrayList<>();

    @GetMapping("/")
    public String getForm(Model model,@RequestParam(required=false)String id){ 
        int index = getIndexFromId(id);
        model.addAttribute("user", index == -1000 ? new User(): users.get(index));
        return "sign-up";
    }
    
    @PostMapping("/submitForm")
    public String handleSubmit(@Valid User user, BindingResult result){
        int index = getIndexFromId(user.getId());
        if(result.hasErrors()){
            return "sign-up";
        }
        
        if(index == -1000){
            users.add(user);
        }else {
            users.set(index,user);
        }
       
        return "redirect:/result";
    }
    
    @GetMapping("/result")
    public String getResult(Model model){
        model.addAttribute("users", users);
        return "result";
    }

    public Integer getIndexFromId(String id){
        for(int i=0;i<users.size();i++){
            if(users.get(i).getId().equals(id)){
                return i;
            }
        }
        return -1000;
}

}
```

My User.java

```java
package com.example.workbook31;

import org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat;

import jakarta.validation.constraints.Email;
import jakarta.validation.constraints.NotBlank;
import jakarta.validation.constraints.Past;
import jakarta.validation.constraints.Size;

import java.util.Date;
import java.util.UUID;


public class User {
    @NotBlank(message = "First name cannot be blank")
    @Size(min=2, message="First name is too short")
    private String firstName;
    
    @NotBlank(message = "First name cannot be blank")
    @Size(min=2, message="First name is too short")
    @LastName
    private String lastName;
    
    @NotBlank(message = "Username cannot be blank")
    @Size(min=7, message= "Username must at least be 7 characters")
    private String userName;
    
    @Email(message = "Invalid Email")
    private String email;
    
    @Past(message = "date of birth must be in the past")
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
    private Date dateOfBirth;
    private String id;
    
    public User() {
        this.id = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }

    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public Date getDateOfBirth() {
        return dateOfBirth;
    }

    public void setDateOfBirth(Date dateOfBirth) {
        this.dateOfBirth = dateOfBirth;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

      
    
    
}
```

My Application.java

```java
package com.example.workbook31;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

}
```

My sign-up.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Sign Up</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/form-stylesheet.css}">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <h2>Javagram</h2>
        <form method="post" th:object="${user}" th:action="@{/submitForm}">
            <p style="color:red" th:errors ="*{firstName}"></p>
            <input type="text" placeholder="First Name" th:field="*{firstName}">
            <p style="color:red" th:errors ="*{lastName}"></p>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Last Name" th:field="*{lastName}">
            <p style="color:red" th:errors ="*{userName}"></p>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Username" th:field="*{userName}" >
            <p style="color:red" th:errors ="*{email}"></p>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Email" th:field="*{email}">
            <p style="font-weight: bold;">Date of Birth</p>
            <input type="date" th:field="*{dateOfBirth}" >
            <p style="color:red" th:errors ="*{dateOfBirth}"></p>
            <input type="hidden" th:field="*{id}" >
            <br><br>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

My pom

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Comment: You shouldn't check `string` for equality in `==` manner

Comment: I used the equals() function and I still get the same error

Comment: I also find this error UnexpectedTypeException: HV000030

Answer (score 1):

#### Short Answer

Your validator should, as your model and your error message imply:

```java
... implements ConstraintValidator<LastName, String>
```

And not `<LastName, User>`.

Accordingly, you should re-implement the `isValid(...)` method: accepting the last name `String` (and not the containing `User`).

If you want to use this annotation on `User` and `String` "fields", you *must* implement an additional `ConstraintValidator<LastName, ...>`, with according "API facade".

This *can* be wired/refered like:

```java
@Constraint(
  validatedBy = {
    StringLastNameValidator.class, 
    UserLastNameValidator.class /*,...*/ 
  }
) // accepts array!;)
```

#### Extended answer

Your (current) validator seems wrong ("Mr. Jack Jack" is invalid, while "Mr `<null>` X" valid!?), but should (if reasoned) be used **on `User`** "fields", e.g ("method parameter" in this case) :

```java
@PostMapping("/submitForm")
    public String handleSubmit(
  @Valid @LastName User user // ! ...
```

...to use it **inside `User`** (on `String` fields), stick to "short answer".

Comment: Thanks...I know how to tackle the problems